# Browse folder from duplicity archive

Tags: backup, duplicity

I have deleted a folder that I should not have deleted and want to bring it back and I am completely certain that is is on my backup drive.
I use `duplicity` and it is set up to backup my home directory to an external drive. What I know about the folder I want to restore is that it was in the `Downloads` folder. How do I list the files that were backed up **in this folder**?

Running
`duplicity list-current-files file:///path_to_backup/my_name/`
takes forever because there are lots of hidden files in my home directory (config, flatpack, whatever...). `grep`ing for `Downloads` does not seem to speed up the process.

Attempting
`duplicity list-current-files file:///path_to_backup/my_name/Downloads`
just tells me that the given path does not correspond to anything backupish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is using the default File manager "Files" and right-click on the location where the missing folder was, then choose "Restore missing files..." and follow the prompts.

So open the Downloads folder and just right click!

This works in Ubuntu 18.04.5